# Swift NOT operator (~) prints different values than when used

Tags: swift, bit-manipulation

**Swift bitwise NOT operator (~) inverts all bits in a number.**

The docs provide the example:

> ```
> let initialBits: UInt8 = 0b00001111
> let invertedBits = ~initialBits  // equals 11110000
> ```

And I can confirm this by printing a String:

```
print(String(invertedBits, radix: 2)) // equals 11110000
```

Given this logic I would expect `~0 to equal 1` and `~1 to equal 0`. However printing these as I did above print something unexpected:

```
 print(String(~0b1, radix: 2)) // equals -10
 print(String(~0b0, radix: 2)) // equals -1
```

When in use I see something different:

```
print(String(0b100 & ~0b111, radix: 2)) // equals 0 just as I would expect 100 & 000  to equal 000
```

but

```
print(String(~0b111, radix: 2)) // equals -1000
```

`~0b111` seems to act as if it were `0b000` but it prints as `-1000`

What's going on here?

Comment: The operator is likely working on all bits in the byte, so `~0b111` is actually  `~0b00000111 = 0b11111000`

Comment: @WillRichardson No. `0b111` is actually "0b00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000000_00000111" and `~0b111` is actually `"0b11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111_11111111_11111000"` It is an `Int` 64 bit not `UInt8` 8 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the documentation provided example, `initialBits` has an explicit type. What is happening can be shown by the following code

```
let number = 0b1 // we don't specify a type, therefore it's inferred

print(type(of: number))           // Int
print(String(~number, radix: 2))  // -10 as you know

print(number.bitWidth)            // 64 because integers have 64 bits

// now if we create a 64 bit number, we can see what happened
// prints -10 because this number is equivalent to the initial number
print(String(~0b0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001, radix: 2))
```

Comment: But for `print(String(0b100 & ~0b111, radix: 2))` we aren't setting a specific type either. Why would this work by returning 0?

Comment: `0b100` has a single one bit with all other positions as zero. `~0b111` has 3 zero bits and 61 one bits. One of the zero bits is in the same position as `0b100`. There is not a single position where both have a one bit. So the result is 64 zero bits. The number 0.

Comment: Because it has a single one bit that means Swift won't assume it's 64 bits, it assumes 3?

Comment: It has 64 bits but only one of them is a 1. `000...00100 & 111...111000` is 0

Comment: I think I see. But why would `print(String(~0b0, radix: 2))` print `-1`? If that is really 64 0's inverted to 64 1s?

Comment: I see now that 64 1's actually equals `-1` as an Int in the context of a signed int that was printed as an Int. If I set `let uint: UInt8 = 0` then I can print `String(~uint, radix: 2)` to see it print out: `11111111`. Is the only way to `invert 0` to get 64 ones that is not a signed int with `Int(~0b0 as UInt64)` so it prints a very large positive number? In playground `Int(~0b0 as UInt64)` shows an error `Not enough bits to represent the passed value`. When does Swift chose unsigned vs signed ints? I think the confusion is mixing between the two.

Comment: Swift uses signed integers unless you specify otherwise. You might want to learn about two's complement, and the range of values that can be represented by signed integers vs unsigned integers.